# as3 child as movieclip - won't accept functions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

this follows on from my last question which I thought was answered but for some reason when I treat a child of my stage (display object) as a movieclip I can't then apply the usual functions that I want to:

```
var mc1:MovieClip = this.getChildByName("mc1") as MovieClip;
if(mc1) {
    mc1.useHandCursor = true;
    mc1.buttonMode = true;
    mc1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fillDriveway);
}
```

Any wisdom would greatly appreciated... and sorry for asking such a similar question as previous...

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: More code from the AS on this project for context:

```
import flash.display.*

ImageUploader.visible = false;

function showUploader(e:MouseEvent):void {
    ImageUploader.visible = true;
    ImageUploader.gotoAndPlay(2);
}

pic.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,addNewPoint);

var n:Number = 0;
var joinPointsArray:Array = new Array;

function addNewPoint(e:MouseEvent):void {
    n++;
    pointNo.text = String(n);
    if(n==1){
        var nextPoint:MovieClip = new mcstart();
        addChild(nextPoint);
        nextPoint.name = "mc"+pointNo.text;
        nextPoint.x = e.target.mouseX;
        nextPoint.y = e.target.mouseY;
    }else{
        var nextPoint2:MovieClip = new newPoint();
        addChild(nextPoint2);
        nextPoint2.name = "mc"+pointNo.text;
        nextPoint2.x = e.target.mouseX;
        nextPoint2.y = e.target.mouseY;
    }

    var joinPoints:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    this.addChild(joinPoints);
    joinPointsArray.push(joinPoints);
    joinPoints.graphics.lineStyle(0.5,0xFF0000);
    joinPoints.graphics.moveTo(this.getChildByName("mc1").x, this.getChildByName("mc1").y);
    for(var i:int=2; i<=n; ++i){
        joinPoints.graphics.lineTo(this.getChildByName("mc"+i).x, this.getChildByName("mc"+i).y);
    }
}

pic.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addNewPoint);

function fillDriveway(eventObject:MouseEvent) {
    var joinPoints:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    this.addChild(joinPoints);
    for(var p:int=0; p<(joinPointsArray.length); ++p) {
        joinPointsArray[p].alpha = 0;
    }
    this.getChildByName("mc1").alpha = 0;
    joinPoints.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 0.7);
    joinPoints.graphics.moveTo(this.getChildByName("mc1").x, this.getChildByName("mc1").y);
    for(var m:int=2; m<=n; ++m){
        joinPoints.graphics.lineTo(this.getChildByName("mc"+m).x, this.getChildByName("mc"+m).y);
    }
    joinPoints.name = "driveshape";
    filledDrive.text = "filled";
}

function undoit(eventObject:MouseEvent) {
    if(n > 0) {
        if(filledDrive.text.indexOf("filled") != -1) {
            this.removeChild(this.getChildAt(this.numChildren -1));
            filledDrive.text = "";
            }else{
            this.removeChild(this.getChildAt(this.numChildren -1));
            this.removeChild(this.getChildAt(this.numChildren -1));
            n--;
            pointNo.text = String(n);
        }
    }
}

function maskDrive(eventObject:MouseEvent) {
    if(filledDrive.text.indexOf("filled") != -1) {
        var finishA:MovieClip = new finishMC();
        this.addChild(finishA);
        finishA.x = 310;
        finishA.y = 100;
        finishA.mask = getChildByName("driveshape");
        finishA.gotoAndPlay(2);
    }
}

//BTN RollOvers
function btn1over(myEvent:MouseEvent) {
    btn1.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
function btn1out(myEvent:MouseEvent) {
    btn1.gotoAndPlay(11);
}
function btn2over(myEvent:MouseEvent) {
    btn2.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
function btn2out(myEvent:MouseEvent) {
    btn2.gotoAndPlay(11);
}
function btn3over(myEvent:MouseEvent) {
    btn3.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
function btn3out(myEvent:MouseEvent) {
    btn3.gotoAndPlay(11);
}
function undoover(myEvent:MouseEvent) {
    undo.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
function undoout(myEvent:MouseEvent) {
    undo.gotoAndPlay(11);
}

//BTN Calls
btn1HIT.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fillDriveway);
btn1HIT.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, btn1over);
btn1HIT.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, btn1out);
btn1HIT.buttonMode = true;
btn1HIT.useHandCursor = true;
btn2HIT.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, maskDrive);
btn2HIT.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, btn2over);
btn2HIT.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, btn2out);
btn2HIT.buttonMode = true;
btn2HIT.useHandCursor = true;
btn3HIT.buttonMode = true;
btn3HIT.useHandCursor = true;
btn3HIT.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, btn3over);
btn3HIT.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, btn3out);
btn3HIT.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showUploader);
undoHIT.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, undoit);
undoHIT.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, undoover);
undoHIT.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, undoout);
undoHIT.buttonMode = true;
undoHIT.useHandCursor = true;

var mc1:MovieClip = this.getChildByName("mc1") as MovieClip;
if(mc1) {
    mc1.useHandCursor = true;
    mc1.buttonMode = true;
    mc1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fillDriveway);
}
```

Comment: Is `mc1` a MovieClip? Is the `if` statement executed? What does "I can't then apply the usual functions" mean?

Comment: "mc1" is a dynamically created movieclip with an instance name "mc1". I then need to reference it as a normal movieclip on the timeline but it won't as it is classed only as a display object. So I define it into a new var called "mc1" as a movieclip hoping I can then apply the usual actions on it that I would a timeline movieclip like those above but it doesn't work. No compiler errors just mc1 doesn't respond to actions applied in my AS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wahoo! Figured it out!

By popping

```
var mc1:MovieClip = this.getChildByName("mc1") as MovieClip;
```

at the end of my AS I was referring to the child "mc1" before it existed - it isn't created until the user clicks somewhere on the "pic" movieclip. So the solution was to bung my actions for "mc1" (including declaring it as a MovieClip) into a separate function:

```
function createstartEndMC():void {
    var startEnd:MovieClip = (this.getChildByName("mc1")) as MovieClip;
    startEnd.useHandCursor = true;
    startEnd.buttonMode = true;
    startEnd.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fillDriveway);
}
```

and then to call this function AFTER "mc1" child is created:

```
function addNewPoint(e:MouseEvent):void {
    n++;
    pointNo.text = String(n);
    if(n==1){
        var nextPoint:MovieClip = new mcstart();
        addChild(nextPoint);
        nextPoint.name = "mc"+pointNo.text;
        nextPoint.x = e.target.mouseX;
        nextPoint.y = e.target.mouseY;
        createstartEndMC();
    }
```

Finally it works and "mc1" (or "startEnd" as I call it once it's created and made into an MC) finally behaves as a normal timeline MC should!

I'm so happy - thanks for all your guidance!

Cam

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the movieclip is placed on stage or actually converted to movieclip?
Try `stage.getChildByName()`. Where did you place this code? Inside a frame or inside a main document class? To be sure you can check the childs are added on stage and see what their names are.
You can use this code

```
        for ( var i :int = 0; i < this.numChildren; i++ )
        {
            babe = this.getChildAt( i );
            if ( babe is MovieClip)  {
                trace( babe.name);
            }
        }
```

I've also seen this, not sure if it works.

```
if (stage.contains(mc1)) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks giannosfor, you can see from the second bit of code I've posted that it is added to the stage and then in the first bit of code that I've declared it to be a movieclip but no joy - even without an if statement it doesn't work:
`var mc1:MovieClip = (this.getChildByName("mc1")) as MovieClip;
 mc1.useHandCursor = true;
 mc1.buttonMode = true;
 mc1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fillDriveway);`

Comment: Again with the example above no compiler errors just no joy either :(

Comment: Does the `mc1` enters the `if` statement? Have you place a `trace` in order to be sure?You can place my code inside in order to see if the `mc1` is casted properly. Or even place a `trace` inside the `fillDriveway` function to see if it interacts but you can't see it.Also I think `mc1.useHandCursor = true` isn't necessary.